# Disable assert for Debug mode

Tags: ios, swift, assert

How can I easily disable `assert` in Swift code while debugging? I've tried several methods:

`Disable Safety Checks`, `NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS`, `Enable Foundation Assertions` , `-assert-config Release` didn't actually help.

Comment: "In `-Ounchecked` builds, condition is not evaluated, but the optimizer may assume that it always evaluates to `true`. Failure to satisfy that assumption is a serious programming error."

Comment: Try with this one it should work `NS_BLOCK_ASSERTIONS=1`

Comment: Are these `assert` statements in your own code that you’re trying to catch? Or assertions thrown by some API? Because I find the `-Ounchecked` (which “Editor” » “Validate Settings...” replaced with “disable safety checks”) does it.

Comment: @Rob this is an external library

Comment: We’d probably need info about that library (did you compile it or was it a compiled framework; which library is this; etc.), and the specific assertion, to help you further. As a general rule, a [minimal, yet complete and verifiable, example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) always helps. We don’t want to see a lot of your code, but rather just the bare minimum we’d need to reproduce the problem you’re describing.

Comment: But, I notice that in Debug build, “Disable Safety Checks” was not sufficient. I had to change “Swift Compiler - Code Generation” » “Optimization Level” » “Debug” from “No optimization -Onone” to `-Ounchecked`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the assertion code was in a framework, so settings `No` on `Enable Foundation Assertion` in the framework build settings did the trick.